# To check whether a tree is bst or not but error occured.Failed case #25/36: unknown signal 11

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

The first line contains the number of vertices n. The vertices of the tree are numbered from 0 to n−1. Vertex 0 is the root. The next n lines contain information about vertices 0, 1, ..., n−1 in order. Each of these lines contains three integers keyi, lefti and righti — keyi is the key of the i-th vertex, lefti is the index of the left child of the i-th vertex, and righti is the index of the right child of the i-th vertex. If i doesn’t have left or right child (or both), the corresponding lefti or righti (or both) will be equal to −1.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;
int check_binary(long long int key1[],long long int left1[],long long int right1[],long long int n, long long int index,long long int max1, long long int min1)
{
    if(index==-1)
        return 1;
    if(key1[index]<min1||key1[index]>max1)
        return 0;
    if((check_binary(key1,left1,right1,n,left1[index],key1[index]-1,min1))&&(check_binary(key1,left1,right1,n,right1[index],max1,key1[index])))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    long long int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    if(n==0)
    {
        cout<<"CORRECT";
            return 0;
    }
    long long int key1[n],left1[n],right1[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>key1[i]>>left1[i]>>right1[i];
    }
    if(check_binary(key1,left1,right1,n,0,INT_MAX,INT_MIN))
    {
        cout<<"CORRECT";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"INCORRECT";
}
```

Comment: From the title this sounds like some sort of online coding challenge.  [Edit] the question to include link to it.  I also see several potential places for errors like this but without example input to recreate the problem they are only guesses, most likely the nonstandard `long long int key1[n]` etc being too large to fit on the stack.

Comment: It's a question from programming assignment of a course.Example inputs are given for small values but not for large values.